Easy streaming parsing of non-uniform data using System.Text.Json
What is the easiest way to do streaming parsing of non-uniform JSON data using System.Text.Json?
I am trying to stream-parse JSON in the SPARQL JSON results format, e.g.:
{ "head": {
    "vars": [ "s" , "p" , "o" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      { 
        "s": { "type": "uri" , "value": "https://example.com/ontology/al/bnode/1" } ,
        "p": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type" } ,
        "o": { "type": "uri" , "value": "https://example.com/ontology/al/Module" }
      } ,
      { 
        "s": { "type": "bnode" , "value": "b0" } ,
        "p": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#rest" } ,
        "o": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil" }
      } ,
      { 
        "s": {
          "type": "triple" , 
          "value": {
            "subject":  { "type": "uri" , "value": "https://example.com/ontology/al/bnode/1798" } ,
            "predicate": { "type": "uri" , "value": "https://example.com/ontology/al/type" } ,
            "object":   { "type": "uri" , "value": "https://example.com/ontology/al/bnode/6" }
          }
        } ,
        "p": { "type": "uri" , "value": "https://example.com/ontology/al/dimensions" } ,
        "o": { "type": "bnode" , "value": "b0" }
      } ,
      { 
        "s": { "type": "uri" , "value": "https://example.com/ontology/al/bnode/1" } ,
        "p": { "type": "uri" , "value": "https://example.com/ontology/al/publisher" } ,
        "o": { "type": "literal" , "value": "Example" }
      }
  ]
 }
}

The head/vars mentions variables, which are specific to the query at hand and bound to specific values in the results/bindings array.
Normally I would JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<T> but since the top-level element is not an array, that does not seem workable. That the individual variable bindings are non-uniform is not a problem per se, as T could be the JsonElement type.
The data is comming from an HTTP stream. For a quasi-long-running query, it would give a better UX if the results could be incrementally integrated into the UI of the client application.
Current types used in parsing:
[<Struct>]
type RdfUri =
    { Value: string }

    member this.Uri = Uri(this.Value)

[<Struct>]
type RdfBlankNode =
    { Value: string }

[<Struct>]
type RdfLiteral =
    { Value: string
      DataType: string voption }

type RdfTriple =
    { Subject: RdfValue
      Predicate: RdfValue
      Object: RdfValue }

[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
type RdfValue =
    | Uri of RdfUri
    | BlankNode of RdfBlankNode
    | Literal of RdfLiteral
    /// RDF-star
    | Triple of RdfTriple

// SPARQL types

type SparqlVariableBinding =
    { Name: string
      Value: RdfValue }

type SparqlVariableBindings = 
    { Bindings: block<SparqlVariableBinding> }

    member this.TryFind(name: string) : RdfValue option =
        this.Bindings
        |> Block.tryFind (fun var -> String.Equals(var.Name, name, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        |> Option.map (fun var -> var.Value)

    member this.Item(name: string) : RdfValue =
        match this.TryFind name with
        | None -> failwith $"Could not find variable %s{name}"
        | Some x -> x

type SparqlHead = { VariableNames: Set<string> }

[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
type SparqlResult =
    | Head of SparqlHead
    | Variables of SparqlVariableBindings

[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
type AsyncSparqlResultSet = AsyncSeq<SparqlResult>


This is not currently implemented out of the box, see JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable should support streaming from nested JSON arrays. #101446.  As a workaround you could use this answer by mtosh to Parsing a JSON file with .NET core 3.0/System.text.Json.  Does that answer your question?  It's not entirely easy though...

What do you plan to do with the "results.bindings[*]" objects as you stream through them?  If you just want to perform some action and move on, you could use a synthetic collection that performs the work without actually collecting the incoming objects.  See e.g. AggregatingCollection<TItem> from this answer to Using System.Text.Json DeserializeAsyncEnumerable to deserialize non-root items.  Does that answer your question?

I would do the same as in the non-streaming version of the code: return  SparqlVariableBinding objects - but in an IAsyncEnumerable<SparqlVariableBinding> (well rather an AsyncSeq<'T> - F#). A separate mapping function will take turn every SparqlVariableBinding into an object for some domain (e.g. an analysis result view model). I do not expect the parsing overhead to be significant enough to warrant too much optimization - but the big latency before getting results at all, is.

Can you share a link or reference to SparqlVariableBinding or otherwise share a [mcve]?   I can't find any reference to it.  Is it something you construct by combining the "head.vars" array with the value of each "results.bindings[*]" item?

I have updated my question with some types that are used in production code. I don't think the exact types are that important.

I don't know if this is what you are looking, but one way to do this is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and/or INotifyCollectionChanged  on your data model or DTOs, then customize your JsonTypeInfo.CreateObject() to add custom PropertyChanged or CollectionChanged events that update your UX as your data is streamed in.  C# demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dqKOUf.

I haven't studied that part of the STJ API (JsonTypeInfo) but I am thinking I may just use this library: https://github.com/bjornharrtell/Utf8JsonStreamReader

Well, for my use-case I figured out how to project the query directly to JSON using the SPARQL ARC engine but others may still find this question interesting outside my use-case.
